# Flexslider 1px less than container and showing 1px of next image

Tags: css, flexslider

I have a percentage container and a 3 box caraousel flexlider, for some reason the flexlider is 1px less than it's container and showing 1px of the next image in the caraousel.

I am not using any borders. You can see this here:

http://dusit.syndacast.com/dusitthani/bangkok

It is not the top slider it's the one below PACKAGES & PROMOTIONS with the 3 boxes.

Even stranger it doesn't happen for all widths, if you resize the window you will see it is correct sometimes but most of the time not.

Thank you!